# Remove user button with confirmation message

Tags: php

I'm doing a forum project. I'm doing the backend part and I want a confirmation message to come out when I press a button and then delete it. I only have the button code.

Comment: Your question is too broad, see [How do I ask a good question](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask)

Comment: another way of doing it  you can put somthing like this in html it will ask on button <button type="button" confirm-click="deleteThat();" confirm-message="are you sure?" confirm-duration="3000">delete</button>

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In Javascript :

```
function ConfirmDelete()
{
  var x = confirm("Are you sure you want to delete?");
  if (x)
      return true;
  else
    return false;
}
```

In HTML :

```
<input type="button" onclick="ConfirmDelete()">
```

Comment: how can I make the font awesome icon inside the button?

Comment: you can create a font awesome icon put it into button Example:
<button><i class="fa fa-shopping-cart"></i> Buy Now </button>